# Angular 5 Observable called multiple times

Tags: angular5

I have a service which works as an intermediate between two component.

```
@Injectable()
export class BreadcrumService {
 invokeEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject();
 invokeEvent$ = this.invokeEvent.asObservable();
}

//component
export class Component implements OnChanges{
 constructor(private breadcrumService: BreadcrumService){
 this.breadcrumService.invokeEvent$.subscribe((data) => {
      // called multiple times
    });
}
}
```

When I subscribe to observable it was called multiple time as I init my component.

Comment: If your `subscribe` is executed multiple times, then your `invokeEvent` subject behind the `invokeEvent$` observable has multiple values being pushed on it.

Comment: finally i got the solution to my problem. I just need to `unsubscribe()` my subscription in component's `ngOnDestroy()`